# Show Text and Hide Image on hover column of table angular2

Tags: html, css, angular, class, ng-style

I am using table to display series of items for my data , every data has an action column and on action column there are images I want to hide image and show text when hover on image and vice-versa(show image and hide text) without hover.

**app.html**

```
 <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data">

      <td >{{item.Title}}</td>
      <td>{{item.CustomerName}}</td>
      <td>{{item.ModifiedDate | date}}</td>
      <td>{{item.RegionId}},{{item.City}}{{item.Country}}</td>
      <td>{{item.BidStatus}}</td>
      <td>
      <label class="col-text"><img src="../../../../assets/app-icons/view.png">View</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

the last column has **label** and also the image but want to hide text the text should be only shown when **hover on image** plus want the functionality with only the hovered column image not with other column images

without hover image is shown
 [image: without hover]

when hover text **View** is shown
[image: with hover]

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: yeah i tried mouseover event  and used ng if but it hide/show all images

Comment: can you share the working code? or an image so that we can understand properly what you need.

Comment: ok wait i will comeoup with example

Comment: so you want to show text(view) only when u hover the image ?

Comment: yeah  want to show text only when hover

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's pretty simple...
update html add `span`

```
<label class="col-text"><img src="../../../../assets/app-icons/view.png"><span>View<span></label>
```

add css/scss

```
.col-text {
  span {
    display: none;
  }
}

.col-text:hover {
  img {
   display: none;
  }

  span {
    display: inline-block; // or block etc;
  }
}
```

Comment: only css not scss

Comment: angular application built in css? :)) / anyway copy the scss and compile it online. https://www.sassmeister.com/